# .htaccess Subdomain's Folder To QueryString

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, subdomain

I need `http://profiles.mysite.com/Me` to show what `http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=Me` would show.

The "Me" changes depending on the username. It can contain spaces and is not a real folder.

I do not want the URL to change in the address bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf`
2. Enable mod_proxy in your `httpd.conf`

Finally put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)(\s.*)?$ $1+$2$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\s $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^profiles\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

This answer now will support any # of spaces in the URI since its a recursion based rule. In other words a URI like this:

```
http://profiles.mysite.com/foo bar baz
```

will be proxied as:

```
http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=foo+bar+baz
```

though URL in browser will remain:

```
http://profiles.mysite.com/foo&20bar%20baz
```

Comment: Thanks, but this causes the URL to change.

Comment: That simply means mod_proxy module is not loaded in httpd.conf. Note that I am using flag `P` instead of flag `R`. See here for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Actually, it worked but when there is a space in a name like "http://profiles.mysite.com/User name" it will only show the profile for "User", ignoring the space and everything after it.

Comment: Pls check the edited code that deals with a space in user name. Note that it deals with one single space only in e.g. `user name` but wouldn't deal with `the user name`.

Comment: That works! However, I have some users with multiple spaces... like "U s e r n a m e".

Comment: Hmm its going to be pretty complicated code in .htaccess if at all it can be done. I will try to come up with the solution.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Or even if there's a way to allow like... up to 10 spaces max by adding on to what you already got somehow?

Comment: The answer that I have provided will support any # of spaces since its a recursion based rule.

Comment: That did not work. It added an extra + at the end of the username. It was proxied as /profile.php?user=User+name+

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following code in the .htaccess file in the web root should give you what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^profiles.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It says "Not Found

The requested URL /Me was not found on this server."

Comment: Put RewriteEngine On at the top of the .htaccess file - and of course make sure that the rewrite module is loaded into your webserver and that the command AllowOverrides All is part of the web directory directives in the conf file.

Comment: All 3 of those things were already done. It still won't work. :(

Comment: Hmmm .. it sounds like the rewrite rule isn't firing then. Can you add logging rules? Line 1: RewriteLog "/usr/local/apache/logs/rewrite.log" Line 2: RewriteLogLevel 4 of course replace the path with the full system path of your log file, make sure it exists and is writable.

Comment: I got several thousands of lines in the logs from that log level.

Comment: Ah, in that case, maybe set it to 2 or 3, and just look at the addition to the log file for one request (do tail -f or something if you can)

Comment: I mean if the rewrite rules are firing, then this one should work as well, unless something is pre-empting it. I checked the rule.

Comment: I forgot to add a virtualhost for profiles.mysite.com and now when I try what you suggested I get a 500 error.

Comment: What do the logs say? :) (main server logs might help here and be more concise as well)

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Hmmm .. is there another .htaccess file in the directory serving mysite.com? Also, append the rule I gave you with "[L]" (without the quotes, one the second line after a space at the end) (edited answer to reflect this)

Comment: No there isn't. Also, it's on a VPS so it isn't some weird shared hosting. It gave a 500 error even with the [L].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11139/discussion-between-ansari-and-dav)